# Is the Abrahamic Covenant an unconditional Covenant for believers today?

Tags: covenant, bible

Is the Abrahamic Covenant an unconditional Covenant for believers today (Genesis 12:1-3)?

I discovered in the Bible that God alone is responsible for the performance of the Abrahamic Covenant for Abraham, but is it the same for believers today?

Comment: Of course, it is.  "All the families on earth will be blessed through you" can be also translated as "all the families on earth will be grafted through you" (through your seed, Gen.22:18 & Romans 11:17-24).

Comment: The root of the word ונברכו is the same as that of מבריך, “to graft.”

Comment: The Abrahamic Covenant was and remains eternal covenant, Gen 13:15, 17:9, 13, 19.

Comment: It is unrelated to today's believers since it was made with Abraham its a promise of the nation.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that the most relevant quotation is "Those who are men of faith are blessed with Abraham who had faith" (Galatians ch3 v9), which echoes the "blessing" of Genesis ch12 v2.

In that sense, we have a relationship with God on the same terms that Abraham had a relationship with God. For that reason, the men of faith are regarded as "sons of Abraham" (Galatians ch3 v7), which is part of the fulfilment of "make you a great nation".

Hence, a little further down the Galatians page, we see the assurance that a covenant cannot be annulled (v15) and that this covenant was not cancelled by the law which came later (v17). We have an inheritance which "God gave to Abraham by a promise" (v18).

There is a slight difference, in that Abraham trusted in that promise (compare Hebrews ch11 vv8-9), and our trust is in the fulfilment of that promise (Galatians ch3 v24).

I'm not sure that "unconditional" is the right word, because "faith" is a kind of condition. It's a question of semantics.

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Abrahamic covenant is still applicable today.  The New Covenant is just a renewal of the same covenant which God has made with us in the past, including the Noahide covenant (see Genesis 6:18; 9:9-17), the Abrahamic covenant (see Genesis 15:18; 17:2-21) , and so on.  Only the covenant which *we* attempted to make with God (see Exodus 24:7), and broke (we cannot keep our promises), is invalid: it is called the Old Covenant.

God's covenant is a promise that we will be enabled to keep His law.  The Ten Commandments are part of His covenant.

> And he was there with the LORD forty days and forty nights; he did
> neither eat bread, nor drink water. And he wrote upon the tables **the
> words of the covenant, the ten commandments.** (Exodus 34:28, KJV)

The Ten Commandments are an enduring part of God's covenant.  There will never come a time when we are supposed to break them.  God's covenant is also called "the everlasting covenant" (see Leviticus 24:8).  All who enter a covenant relationship with God, enter His covenant.

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions.